# Extract link from IMAP message

Tags: php, email, anchor, imap, extract

i need to extract an URL from an IMAP message, so far i have been able to extract the message in plain text but not the link, i could really use some help here. Here's what i got so far

```
$section    = empty( $attachments ) ? 1 : 1.2;  
$text       = imap_fetchbody($connection, $msgno, $section );

echo $text."<hr/>";
```

I tried changing the section number from 1 : 1.1 to 1: 1.2 but it didn't help.

I need to extract the mail as html so it contains the link, what do i need to change to get the link?

Comment: is the link inside of the `$text` variable. please post an example what you are currently seeing echoed. it might be as simple as `preg_match()` with an expression for the `a href="neededURL"` if you are not trying to get the url from a link inside the message then please edit your question to clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some bugs in the code above:

- Using `1.2` as a floating point number instead of a string. It's a string and it's only sheer luck that your `1.2` is not getting converted as `1.2000000001`.
- Having a hardcoded part number in case the mail comes with multiple body parts -- read the description in [RFC 3501, p. 56](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#page-56) for details on what these body parts are, how they work and how to find out which ones are relevant for you
- Not performing any decoding of the `Content-Transfer-Encoding` or dealing with character set conversions. You are apparently interested in text parts of a message, these can arrive in multiple encodings like `quoted-printable` or `base64` which you will have to decode. If you'd like to play it safe (you should, it's 2013 already and there are funny characters in URLs, not speaking about the IDNs), also converted from their charset into unicode and only then matched for contents.
- You should probably check the MIME types of at least all top-level body parts so that you do not try to detect "links" within the attached images or undecoded, binary representaiton of zip files, etc.